# I cant run inet 3.4.0 simulation examples

Tags: omnet++, inet

When i try to run the examples in inet framework i get this error 
 Error: Attempt to load the oppsim shared library more than once. This usually happens when part of your simulation is using release libraries while other parts are using the debug version. Make sure to rebuild all parts of your model in either release or debug mode!

Please how can i resolve this issue

Comment: Find out why you're loading the same library multiple times, as described by the error message. If you can't find it, try rolling back to an earlier version and go through your changes to track down the bug.

Comment: I tried everything i can think of, its still not working...please someone should help me

Comment: Did you try to build first OMNET and then INET in only the debug or release version? For OMNeT, you can select the version while doing the make procedure on the command line (`make mode=DEBUG`) for example. For INET, you can also select the version to build in the IDE (normally, the debug-release should be selected automatically).

Comment: Yes i did. OMNET is working just fine. Am getting this error while trying to run simulation examples on INET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew finally after spending days on it, i figured it out. Just change the configuration setting from debug (active) to release (active) and rebuild INET again then try to run the examples... Thank you guys for your replies